# Invertir los elementos de una lista con recursión

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, funciones

Debo hacer una función recursiva que invierta los strings dentro de una lista, pero no debe invertir las posiciones de esta. Hasta el momento llevo esto, cumple con invertir los strings pero también invierte las posiciones y no debe pasar eso. Ayuda!

```py
def estavaina(objeto):
    if type(objeto) == str:
        if len(objeto)==0:
            return objeto
        else:
            return estavaina(objeto[1:])+objeto[0]
        
    elif type(objeto)== list:
        if len(objeto) == 0:
            return []
        return [estavaina(objeto.pop())] + estavaina(objeto)
```

Comment: podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que esperas hacer con tu función? ya que no es muy claro

Comment: No podrías simplemente usar `list(map(lambda str:str[::-1],lista))`?? Por que usar recursión?

Answer (score 1):

No se por que usar recursividad en algo tan básico como eso, pero supongo que algo así podría satisfacer lo que pides:

```
def invertirStrLista(lista,n=0):
    if n==len(lista):
        return lista
    else:
        lista[n] = lista[n][::-1]
        n += 1
        return invertirStrLista(lista,n)

lst = ["perro","gato","leon"]
print(invertirStrLista(lst)) # Salida: ['orrep', 'otag', 'noel']
```

Otras alternativas sin recursividad mucho mas elegantes son:

```
def invertirStrLista(lista):
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        lista[i] = lista[i][::-1]
    return lista

lst = ["perro","gato","leon"]
print(invertirStrLista(lst)) # Salida: ['orrep', 'otag', 'noel']
```

Recorres la lista y con `lista[i][::-1]` inviertes cada uno de las cadenas sin modificar su posición en la lista. Alternativamente podrías usar:

```
def invertirStrLista(lista):
    return list(map(lambda str:str[::-1],lista));

lst = ["perro","gato","leon"]
print(invertirStrLista(lst)) # Salida: ['orrep', 'otag', 'noel']
```

Comment: Por completar, te faltaría la comprensión de listas: `def invertirStrLista(lista): return [p[::-1] for p in lista]`

Comment: @abulafia Gracias por el aporte! Olvide la forma mas "pythonica" de todas XD

Answer (score 1):

Estabas relativamente cerca de la solución, pero:

- Te complicaste demasiado mirando si el elemento es cadena o lista. La función debería funcionar exclusivamente sobre listas (cuyos elementos sean cadenas)
- Para invertir una cadena puedes usar `cadena[::-1]` en vez de hacerlo recursivamente (y así evitas la complicación señalada en el punto anterior).
- Al usar `.pop()` estás destruyendo la lista original. Es decir, si llamas a la función con `estavaina(mi_lista)`, al retornar `mi_lista` quedará vacía, lo que es un efecto secundario probablemente indeseado.
- El método `.pop()` extrae el último elemento, en lugar del primero, lo que es la causa de que la lista te venga al final en orden reverso.

Teniendo en cuenta estas observaciones, una versión mucho más simple sería:

```
def invierte_letras(lista):
  if not lista:
    return []
  return [lista[0][::-1]] + invierte_letras(lista[1:])
```

La condición de parada es recibir una lista vacía. En otro caso se retorna la lista resultado de concatenar la primera palabra "del revés", con el resultado de llamar recursivamente para el resto de la lista.

Ejemplo de funcionamiento:

```
a = ["pepe", "juan", "foobar", "spam", "eggs"]
del_reves = invierte_letras(a)
print(a)
print(del_reves)
```

Produce lo siguiente (donde se ve que la lista original `a` no ha sido alterada):

```
['pepe', 'juan', 'foobar', 'spam', 'eggs']
['epep', 'nauj', 'raboof', 'maps', 'sgge']
```